# count of subsets which sums upto given number(repetition is allowed). Not getting correct ouput

Tags: java

```
Input: 4
       1 3 5 7
       8
```

```
Output: 6
```

whats wrong with this code?

It is similar to the sum of subset problem. The only difference here is that we have infinite supplies of array elements.
My output:
7 1 
7 1 
5 3 
5 3 
5 1 1 1 
5 3 
5 3 
5 1 1 1 
3 3 1 1 
3 3 1 1 
3 1 1 1 1 1 
3 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
13
I am printing all combinations that the code is counting for refernce. Some combinations are printed twice or thrice. What changes should I do to skip repeated combinations??

```
import java.util.*;
public class denomination {
    public static int result=0;
    public static void count(int n, int[] arr, int sum, Stack<Integer> out){
        if(sum<0 || n<=0){
            return;
        }
        if(sum==0){
            result++;
            for (int x : out)
                System.out.print(x + " ");
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }
        out.push(arr[n-1]);
        count(n, arr, sum-arr[n-1], out);
        count(n-1, arr, sum-arr[n-1],out);
        if(!out.empty())
            out.pop();
        count(n-1, arr, sum, out);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        int sum = in.nextInt();
        Stack<Integer> out = new Stack<Integer>();
        count(n, arr, sum, out);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `1,7` and `7,1` are both the same *subset* that sums to 8.

We can represent the *subset* as a `Map<Integer, Integer>` where:

- Key - element from `arr`.
- Value - count of uses.

With this representation, both `1,7` and `7,1` will be represented as the `Map`= `{1:1, 7:1}` (keys are not ordered in `Map`).

We can store unique *subsets* in `Set<Map<Integer, Integer>>`.

Now it's straightforward to code:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void count(int[] arr, int targetSum, Map<Integer, Integer> currMap, Set<Map<Integer, Integer>> subsets) {
        if (targetSum > 0) { 
            for (int integer : arr) {
                Map<Integer, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<>(currMap);
                Integer integerUseCount = currMap.getOrDefault(integer, 0);
                newMap.put(integer, integerUseCount + 1);

                count(arr, targetSum - integer, newMap, subsets); // "Let's try with this"
            }
        } else if (targetSum == 0) { // We found a subset
            subsets.add(currMap);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Map<Integer, Integer>> subsets = new HashSet<>();
        count(new int[]{1, 3, 5, 7}, 8, new HashMap<>(), subsets);
        System.out.println("Output: "+ subsets.size());
        System.out.println("Subsets are:");
        subsets.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Output: 6
Subsets are:
{1=2, 3=2}
{1=5, 3=1}
{1=3, 5=1}
{1=1, 7=1}
{5=1, 3=1}
{1=8}
```